# Blank output on 3D Map view on height data with projected CRS - QGIS 3.30.3

Tags: coordinate-system, 3d, mapping

I have some CSV height data which has been imported as Lat,Lon,Height with a CRS of EPSG 4326.I want to produce a 3D view which shows each height element as a column and ideally join the points with an overlaid surface. like this:

[image]

To get the projected CRS required by the 3D view I changed the CRS to Zone 31N which is the nearest fit. I could not find [Zone 31U which seems to be the one for N51.7 1.5E.](https://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html) Assuming UTM30N is near enough I'm happy with that.

However, the display I get in 3D view is completely blank.

Could it be that the UTM31N will not work with those coordinates? If so then how do I get UTM31U which seems to be the right one?

Some hints would be appreciated.